# Can I ask a question about assembly language and Raspberry Pi in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, search, help-center

I am an OS developer and I don't know if anyone on Stack Overflow knows 6502 assembly language.

Can I ask about 6502 Assembly and Raspberry Pi 4 on Stack Overflow? Is there another Stack Exchange community for that?

Comment: If that is the 6502 that is used in a Commodore 64 then you can try [Retro Computing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as well. And there is a whole site for [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Actually I dont have a Commodore 64 nor Commodore VIC-20. I don't even have a Raspberry PI!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Stack Overflow you can ask questions about

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Writing assembly language falls into that category. Questions need to be focused, researched and clear. And on Stack Overflow they often include some code to explain and/or provide context for your problem.

Going to the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) you can find the [6502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/6502) tag and 256 users seem to watch that tag. There are not many question about it (161 in total) so it is not a high traffic tag. There is also a generic [assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assembly) but do read their wiki that would tell you to also include the specific CPU tag.

If the 6502 is indeed about that ancient CPU then you might have luck on [Retro Computing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but they exclude questions that are about emulating a CPU on specific hardware. They do have a [6502](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6502) tag with 94 questions (51 watchers), so while your exact question might not fit there that is valuable to research (and include what you found in your question)

Around the network there is also a site specific to [Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). It looks they accept questions about Operating Systems but they don't seem to be keen on in-depth programming problems.

For all the above: read the tag wikis, existing questions and answers, the help center and Meta sites before you compose your question and choose the right site.